# Check class has another class and add class to next child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following set up in my navigation:

```
<div class="navegacion"><a href="/sobre" title="Sobre Nostros">Sobre Nosotros</a></div>
<div class="navegacion"><a href="/noticias" title="Noticias">Noticias</a></div>
<div class="navegacion"><a href="/elementos" title="Elementos">Elementos</a></div>
<div class="navegacion"><a href="/lugares" title="Lugares">Lugares</a></div>
<div class="navegacion"><a href="/propositos" title="Propositos">Propositos</a></div>
<div class="navegacion"><a href="/esculeas" title="Escuelas">Escuelas</a></div>
```

when the user goes to a page for example `www.example.com/sobre` a new class is added to `sobre` so it looks like those

```
<div class="navegacion seleccionado"><a href="/sobre" title="Sobre Nostros">Sobre Nosotros</a></div>
```

I know how I can check if the class navegacion has a class `seleccionado`, but what I want to do is for the following child `navegacion` that has a class `seleccionado` to add a class `oscuro`, so it would look like this if I am in page `sobre`

```
<div class="navegacion seleccionado"><a href="/sobre" title="Sobre Nostros">Sobre Nosotros</a></div>
<div class="navegacion oscuro"><a href="/noticias" title="Noticias">Noticias</a></div>
```

or like this if I am in page `noticias` it would look like this

```
<div class="navegacion"><a href="/sobre" title="Sobre Nostros">Sobre Nosotros</a></div>
<div class="navegacion seleccionado"><a href="/noticias" title="Noticias">Noticias</a></div>
<div class="navegacion oscuro"><a href="/elementos" title="Elementos">Elementos</a></div>
```

and so on

I thought I could do it like this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if($(".navegacion").hasClass("seleccionado")) {
        $(this).next().addClass("oscuro");
    }
});
```

but its clearly not working.

Comment: When dynamically adding `seleccionado` to the first element, why not add `oscuro` to the next element at the same time? One rule. You should post the primary script in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where `this` does not refer to the element its refers to `document` object. So select the element with both class and do the same.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".navegacion.seleccionado").next().addClass("oscuro");
});
```

Comment: Thank @pranav. Your suggestion was something I tried and it just made me realize that my styles were been cached, but it worked. Thanks!